# Envio de E-mail c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-cli

Galera , preciso de ajuda. tenho a seguinte controller para envio de email, onde envio um email para recupeção de senha. essa email que sera enviado sera de um html simples que tenho na pasta templates. Minha duvida é a seguinte como faço para passar dados do usuario para essa templete, para que na hora do envio chegue esse dados na caixa do usuario.

```
        GmailEmailService gmail = new GmailEmailService();
        EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage();

        //ler o caminho do arquivo html
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("./Emails/templates/EsqueceuASenha.html");

        msg.Body = sr.ReadToEnd();
        msg.IsHtml = true;
        msg.Subject = "Recuperação de Senha";
        msg.ToEmail = emailPara.EmailRecuperacao;

        gmail.SendEmailMessage(msg);



        return RedirectToAction("Login");
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa colocar alguma marcação para substituir o valor do arquivo estático por sua variável dinâmica.

Por exemplo, no seu `EsqueceuASenha.html`

```
<html>
   <body> 
      <b> Sua nova senha provisórioa é:</b> ##NOVA_SENHA##
   </body>
</html>
```

Já no code-behind, você substitui o `##NOVA_SENHA##` pelo valor que desejar...

```
GmailEmailService gmail = new GmailEmailService();
EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage();

//ler o caminho do arquivo html
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("./Emails/templates/EsqueceuASenha.html");

string htmlBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
htmlBody.Replace("##NOVA_SENHA##","admin1234");

msg.Body = htmlBody;
msg.IsHtml = true;
msg.Subject = "Recuperação de Senha";
msg.ToEmail = emailPara.EmailRecuperacao;

gmail.SendEmailMessage(msg);

return RedirectToAction("Login");
```